# Quasar q-timeline shows no connecting line

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I create a Quasar q-timeline the following way:

```
<template v-slot:after>
      <q-scroll-area style="height: 760px; max-width: 100vh;">
        <div class="q-px-lg q-py-md" style="padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 20px;">
          <q-timeline color="secondary" v-for="(item, index) in timelineItems" :key="index">
            <q-timeline-entry icon="security">
              <template v-slot:subtitle>
                {{ item.date + " – " + item.modification_type }}
              </template>
              <q-timeline-content>
                <div v-html="item.content"></div>
              </q-timeline-content>
            </q-timeline-entry>
          </q-timeline>
        </div>
      </q-scroll-area>
    </template>
```

The timeline works but shows no connecting line on the left:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop timeline entries not the q-timeline itself.

```
<q-timeline color="secondary">
  <q-timeline-entry
    v-for="(item, index) in timelineItems"
    :key="index"
    icon="security"
  >
  </q-timeline-entry>
</q-timeline>
```